# Problems loading shaders on a 64-bit version of the application

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

Migrating from 32x to 64x version android game (ndk, openGL ES2). in the 64x some shaders cannot load

```
GLPROGOBJt fnaShaderUtils_Load( GLenum type, GLchar const* source )
{
    // Compile the shader
#if defined(FNPLATFORM_PC) && defined(FNRENDERER_GLES2)
    fnSCOPEDLOCK lock(fnaShaderUtils_CritSec);
#endif

    GLPROGOBJt shader;
    shader = glCreateShader(type);
    if( !shader )
        return 0;

    // Load the shader source
    glShaderSource( shader, 1, &source, NULL );
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what _"cannot load"_ means. What error code(s) are you getting?

Comment: This means "If (!shader) return 0;" - returns 0.

Comment: *"some shaders cannot load"* - does this means it depends on the `type` of the shader?

Comment: no, it doesn't correlate with type